# How to check for empty passwords?

Tags: login, password, authentication

Looking at all the ssh-login attempts by script-kiddies I assume that there are messed up systems connected to the internet that have password-less accounts set up.

But how to check a Linux/Unix system for such accounts (perhaps created by a broken installer script, a confused admin or something like this)?

As first approximation I can think of something like:

```
$ grep '^[^:]\+::' /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
```

Prints all accounts with an empty password - but perhaps on the concrete system such accounts  are not even a problem because no program accepts empty entries - c.f. password(5):

> However, some applications which read the
>          /etc/passwd file may decide not to permit any access at all if the password field is blank.

But what about hashed **empty** strings as passwords (e.g. `crypt("")`)?

How to check for them?

And how to check accounts when more sophisticated account databases are in use (NIS, LDAP, ...)?

Comment: No answer, but possibly related; using [`passwdqc`](http://www.openwall.com/passwdqc/) you can enforce a minimum password strength at the moment the password is changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to find encrypted empty or weak passwords is to use a password cracker like  [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/).

If you are using NIS or LDAP you need first to extract the password hashes from the database  - one way is via `getent`, see the [answer from maxschlepzig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33919/15241)

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the last part of the question:

`getent` abstracts away database specifics, e.g. you can use

```
$ getent passwd
$ getent shadow
```

to access these databases independent of the configured mechanism (files, LDAP, NIS ...).